# CSS ARGB RGBA hex formats

Tags: html, css, colors, hex, rgba

For a jQuery colorpicker I've been working on (https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker), I've been asked to implement hex-ARGB (`#AARRGGBB`) parsing.

However I'm weary to implement hex-ARGB as CSS currently supports the `RGBA(r,g,b,a)` syntax and, if hex is ever supported, will be more likely to support `#RRGGBBAA` syntax.

On the other hand, IE's `filter` CSS tags already use `#AARRGGBB`. However, neither format is an actual standard of any kind.

My colorpicker already supports all standard CSS/HTML syntax and has output formatting flexible enough to output most non-standard formats you might want. The problem is input; parsing. There's no reasonable way to distinguish between the two formats, so I can't have both of them parsed automatically.

Does anybody know of any strong argument for or against either `#AARRGGBB` or `#RRGGBBAA` for use in a colorpicker on the web?

Comment: @minitech: Its already planned in CSS4-Color section : http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you include a small check box / radio buttons and have one automatic?

Also, how often does anyone do what IE does? =p I've actually never seen ARGB in anything I've ever done. Even other Microsoft products.

I typed 'ARGB vs RGBA' in the search engine and found [not much useful](http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2005-January/002648.html), except for the fact that after the first page of results, almost no search results included ARGB, which further seems to indicate it's lack of use.